# Skip lines and start read from specific line C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am reading from a file and I am trying to skip first two lines and start reading from the third one. I've checked other questions which were answered but none of them worked on unity for some reason. I get several errors however it should work.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
string line = "";  

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)  
{
    string[] words = line.Split(' ');
    string type = words[0];
    float x = float.Parse(words[1]);
    ....
}
```

Comment: What errors? I don't see any attempt to skip the first two lines in the code you've shown. The simplest way to do so would be to add `reader.ReadLine();` twice before the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, we can try to use `File.ReadAllLines` which will return all line of text content from your file text and then start reading on the third line (array start as 0, so that the third line might be `contents[2]`).

```
var contents = File.ReadAllLines(path);

for (int i = 2; i < contents.Length; i++)
{
    string[] words = contents[i].Split(' ');
    string type = words[0];
    float x = float.Parse(words[1]);
}
```

If we know the `Encoding` of the file we can try to set `Encoding` to the second parameter in `File.ReadAllLines`

Comment: This was my first thought as well unless the file is so large it's a problem to read it all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to D-Shih's solution, is one using `File.ReadLines`, which returns an `IEnumerable<string>`:

```cs
var lines = File.ReadLines(path);

foreach (string line in lines.Skip(2))
{
    string[] words = line.Split(' ');
    string type = words[0];
    float x = float.Parse(words[1]);
    // etc.
}
```

The benefit of this approach over D-Shih's is that you don't have to read the entire file into memory at once to process it, so this solution is analogous to your existing solution's use of `StreamReader`.

---

As a solution for directly fixing your problem, you just need to call `ReadLine` twice before getting into the loop (to skip the two lines), though I'd argue the solution above is more legible:

```cs
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line = "";  
    
    // skip 2 lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        reader.ReadLine();
    }

    // read file normally
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)  
    {
        string[] words = line.Split(' ');
        string type = words[0];
        float x = float.Parse(words[1]);
        ....
    }
}
```

Notice that I've also wrapped the reader in a `using`, so that the file handle will be closed & disposed of once the loop completes, or in case of an exception being thrown.

Comment: .ReadLines shows an error. Is there smh sth I have to import in the unity script?

Comment: @xs0mE1, since you're using `StreamReder` it seems likely that you have therefore included `using System.IO;`.  [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.0) has been part of .NET Framework since 4.0, and I thought Unity used at least that version based on [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html)? Perhaps you need to try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/unity-scripting-upgrade#enabling-the-net-4x-scripting-runtime-in-unity).

Comment: I should've set it in the player settings, thanks a lot. <3